# How can i map array value?

Tags: jquery, node.js, jquery-ui, autocomplete

Actually I need to do an autocomplete with jquery.ui, the source is like this:

```
[ { Nom: 'user', 'Utilisateur mail': 'user1', 'MDP mail': 'ac14yibd', 'Société': 'truc', ID: 233 }, 
{ Nom: 'user', 'Utilisateur mail': 'user1', 'MDP mail': 'ac14yibd', 'Société': 'truc', ID: 234 } ]
```

The response is an complete array :

```
[ { Nom: 'user', 'Utilisateur mail': 'user1', 'MDP mail': 'ac14yibd', 'Société': 'truc', ID: 233 }]
```

And I need to map the values of keys 'Nom' and 'ID' to 'label' and 'value' for the .autocomplete response.

What is the best way to achieve it?

My semi working actual code :

```
   $(function() {
 $("#search-query").autocomplete({
   source : function (request, response) {
     $.ajax({
       url: "/search_member",
       type: "GET",
       data: request,
       sucess: function (data) {
         response($.map(data, function (el) {
           return {
             label: el.Nom,
             value: el.ID
           };
           }));
       }
     });
   },
   minLength: 3,
   focus: function (event, ui) {
     this.value = ui.item.label;
     event.preventDefault();
   },
   select: function (event, ui) {
     this.value = ui.item.label;
     $(this).next("input").val(ui.item.value);
     event.preventDefault();
     $( "#quicksearch" ).submit();
   }
  });
 });
```

Thanks :D

Comment: what you tried so far ??

Comment: i have edit the main, for showing my actual code

Comment: What do you mean by *"semi working "*? What's the problem with this code? What does this has to do with `node.js`?

Comment: i say semi workking because, the ajax request is correctly parsed in my router, but i don't know if the return is wrong or my front JS code is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with side effects.

```
function adjust(response) {
  return response.map(function(r) {
    r.label = r.Nom;
    r.value = r.ID;
    delete r.Nom;
    delete r.ID;
    return r;
  });
}
```

Comment: i tried, but i think the ajax request is not sucessfull, because i have tried with a simple alert("test") if sucess but nothing is shown.
Maybe my express router is not set correctly

Comment: What is the problem with OP's code? what are the side effects?

Comment: The code wasn't there when I answered the question. Side effects because array elements are modified and not copied.